# How to use useState hook to set markup text?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component with the following hook:-

```
const [imagePreview, setImagePreview] = useState('');
```

Later on, the change event, I have this:-

```
    if (imagePreviewUrl) {
  setImagePreview( (<div>
    <br/> <img src={imagePreviewUrl} alt="icon" width="200" /> 
    </div>));
}
```

Looks like it doesn't set anything. how do I set it? I could do it as:-

```
  let imagePreview = null;
if (imagePreviewUrl) {
  imagePreview = (<div>
    <br/> <img src={imagePreviewUrl} alt="icon" width="200" /> 
    </div>);
}
```

But it is bit ugly. I think useState is the recommended way to do it.

**Update with more code:-**

```
  const fileChangedHandler = event => {
setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = () => {
setImagePreviewUrl(reader.result);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0])
if (imagePreviewUrl) {
// can't break into multiline, sytax error 
setImagePreview('(<div><br/> <img src={imagePreviewUrl} alt="icon" width="200" /> </div>)');
```

}

```
return (
 <div>
 <label>Profile picture: </label>
  <input className="Column" type="file" accept="image/*" 
       onChange={(e) => {fileChangedHandler(e)}} />
  // I want to show the selected image here as preview before upload 
  { imagePreview }
  </div>
 )
```

Hopefully, I will give a clear understanding. What is my intention?

Comment: Is the `if (imagePreviewUrl)` check evaluating to `true`? And what does the "change event" look like exactly, you're only showing a part of it. How does it get triggered?

Comment: Pls, check now. I added more code. Hopefully, it shows what is expected here?

Comment: I see what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're having issues is because you're trying to access the state of `imagePreviewUrl` right after you update it with `setImagePreviewUrl` - this will **not work**.

```js
const fileChangeHandler = (event) => {
  // ...
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    // this is asynchronous
    // so this definitely wouldn't get
    // executed before you get to the `if` statement below
    // also, `setImagePreviewUrl` is asynchronous as well
    setImagePreviewUrl(reader.result)
  }
  // ...
  if (imagePreviewUrl) {
    // the old value of imagePreviewUrl is being used
    // here, and since the initial value evaluates to 
    // `false`, the `setImagePreview` call below
    // never gets executed
  }
}
```

Your new value for `imagePreviewUrl` won't be available immediately because it's asynchronous, so you should probably create a separate hook that listens for changes to `imagePreviewUrl` and updates `imagePreview`.

```js
function App() {
  const [imagePreviewUrl, setImagePreviewUrl] = React.useState("");
  const [imagePreview, setImagePreview] = React.useState(null);

  const fileChangedHandler = () => {
    setImagePreviewUrl(
      "https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"
    );
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (imagePreviewUrl !== "") {
      const image = (
        <div>
          <img alt="fruit" src={imagePreviewUrl} />
        </div>
      );
      setImagePreview(image);
    }
  }, [imagePreviewUrl]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={fileChangedHandler}>
        Trigger file change handler.
      </button>
      {imagePreview}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a working example:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-voice-j40xr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: May I know why "Your new value for imagePreviewUrl won't be available immediately"?  I was guessing this is a synchronous call and it should set immediately.  Never mind, I am learning reactjs.

Comment: @masiboo It's not an asynchronous call. As per docs, "The setState function is used to update the state. It accepts a new state value and enqueues a re-render of the component." Similar to calling `this.setState` in `class-based components`, you will have to "wait" until next render to access the latest value of your state variable. See here for more if you'd like - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/5862900

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recommended approach, what you want is a [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#___gatsby):

```
const [imagePreview, setImagePreview] = useState(false);

if (imagePreviewUrl) {
  setImagePreview(true);
}

return (
  imagePreview && (
    <div>
      <br /> <img src={imagePreviewUrl} alt="icon" width="200" />
    </div>
  )
);
```

Comment: I didn't test it. Definitely it will work. I am trying to achieve it a bit cleaner way by the hooks.